# How to encapsulate std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a class with a `std::function` member and a `operator()` that would call the said member. Here is what I tried:

```
template <class R, class... Args>
class Func{
    public:
    Func(std::function<R(Args...)> fnx) : fn(fnx) {} //Error
    R operator()(Args... a) { return fn(a...); }     //Error
    private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> fn;                    //Error
};
```

However, I get a mysterious error

`error: function returning a function`

in lines indicated as `Error`, that I don't understand --- I don't see any function being returned. Where is it, and how can I fix it?

Full not-working example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/603a84184d9666a8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }       

template <class R, class... Args>
class Func{
    public:
    Func(std::function<R(Args...)> fnx) : fn(fnx) {}
    R operator()(Args... a) { return fn(a...); }
    private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> fn;
};

Func<int(int,int)> foox;

int main() {
    std::cout << foox(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did include the MCVE, did I not?

Comment: Well, not really. The code of the class itself is fine, and that was only code included in the question. I needed to go to the external site to spot the error. As I understand it, the links to external sites should only be addition, but the minimal working example should be the part of the question itself. Now its kinda fixed (I'm not sure if code needs to be duplicated, though).

Comment: Then why not just say *that* about the external site links? MCVE was available, just not the way you expected. I wanted to keep the question itself short and clean, so I opted to put the full code under a link instead - that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
template<typename F>
class Func;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Func<R(Args...)> {
    // ...
};
```

Otherwise, you are misusing `Func` the way you defined it.
In other terms, here is your example code once fixed:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }

template<typename F>
class Func;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
class Func<R(Args...)> {
public:
    Func(std::function<R(Args...)> fnx) : fn(fnx) {}
    R operator()(Args... a) { return fn(a...); }
private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> fn;
};

Func<int(int,int)> foox{foo};

int main() {
    std::cout << foox(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is what I wanted to achieve. I thought the `Func<R(Args...)>` is something that works on its own, and does not need to be declared as a specialization of a generic `F`.

Comment: The question itself gets downvoted too. While the problem may be basic, I don't really understand why it is voted as such.

Answer (score 2):

In this line...

`Func<int(int,int)> foox`

...you are passing `int(int,int)` as `R`, while `Args...` is empty. The error is more obvious in Clang:

```
a.cpp:9:24: error: function cannot return function type 'int (int, int)'
    Func(std::function<R(Args...)> fnx) : fn(fnx) {}
                       ^
a.cpp:15:20: note: in instantiation of template class 'Func<int (int, int)>' requested here
Func<int(int,int)> foox;
                   ^
a.cpp:10:5: error: function cannot return function type 'int (int, int)'
    R operator()(Args... a) { return fn(a...); }
    ^
a.cpp:12:19: error: function cannot return function type 'int (int, int)'
    std::function<R(Args...)> fn;
                  ^
```

The right way to declare `foox` would be `Func<int, int, int> foox;`.

Comment: Maybe show the right way to do it? `Func<int, int, int> foox;`

Comment: Even if it works, I suspect it is not *the right way* as intended by the OP.

Comment: @skypjack I hope that this suspicion didn't make you downvote this answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Besides the correct declaration of foox (like cubuspl42 mentioned) you are also missing to pass the required the foo function as the constructor argument.

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }       

template <class R, class... Args>
class Func{
private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> fn;
public:
    Func(std::function<R(Args...)> fnx) : fn(fnx) {}
    R operator()(Args... a) { return fn(a...); }

};

int main() {
    Func<int, int, int> foox(foo);
    std::cout << foox(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

```

Comment: I think the OP wants to define his function as `Func<int(int, int)>` instead of `Func<int, int, int>`, as done in his example.

Comment: @skypjack Why not ask OP?

Comment: Ah, you are right about passing the right argument to the constructor. I would probably find that problem once the current one was gone.